# Can the Energized passive of Rapid Firecannon apply critical strikes?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that the Statikk Shiv's Shiv Lightning can critical strike. Is the Rapid Firecannon's Energized passive also able to critically strike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the wiki states it but also the item description themselves:

**Stattik Shiv**:

> 35% Attack Speed
>
> 30% Critical Hit Chance
>
> 5% Movement Speed
>
> Unique Passive - Shiv Lightning: Your Energized attacks deal 50~150 bonus magic damage (Based on level) to up to 5 targets on hit (deals +50% bonus damage to minions and can **critically strike**).

**Rapid Fire Cannon**:

> 30% Attack Speed
>
> 30% Critical Strike
>
> 8% Movement Speed
>
> Unique Passive - Firecannon: Your energized attacks gain 35% increased range (+150 range maximum) and deal 50~200 bonus magic damage (based on level) on hit.

You might take a look into this video as well since there is the opinion spread that you can receive superhuman powers receiving both of those items, but that is not true:

Comment: So it doesn't crit cause it doesn't say it will ?

Comment: All spells and item effects which are able to hit critically are shown correcly.  if it would be different one of millions players wouldve noticed. The only correct answer would thus be to ask Riot why they didn't implement it like this and to post their statement. A reason that statikks can hit critically is probably that the damage and thus the ability to clear waves scales better

Comment: I thought about asking if the firecannon would "crit" if you would have both shiv and firecannon. But then I read the 5.24 patch notes...

Comment: @Gnarly404 It says it takes the highest damage... wonder if that takes into account a critical from shiv or only base damage.

Comment: I still do not get the yes/no conclusion and I don't want to watch a video for it.